# sending data to an intent depending on a view (a radio button)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-alertdialog, radio-group

i have an activity showing a dialog which contains radioButtons, and to buttons (Ok,cancel)

1. can i launch an activity from this dialog ?
2. how to send the id of the radioButton selected to the second activity ?

Comment: Imad DZ : check the answers below .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `onClick()` method of the OK Button, you can add this code to start another Activity and pass the id of the checked radio button  :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActitvity.class);
intent.putextras("extra_selected_radio_button", checkedRadioButton.getId());
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the `onCreate()` method of the `SecondActivity` , you can retrieve the id of the selected radio button like this :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int radioButtonId = intent.getIntExtra("extra_selected_radio_button", -1); // -1 is the default value
```

**PS : Check this [tutorial](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/117/how-to-switch-between-different-activities-in-android/) to learn more about sending data between activities in Android.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

1. On the OK button listener just do `startActivity(intent)`
2. Before the previous method call you have to put an extra in the intent, like so `intent.putExtra("radioButtonId", radioButtonValue)`

Answer (score 0):

To start an activity from your dialog you'll have to add this into your button's onClick() code:

```
Intent intentLoad = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourNewActivity.class);
startActivityForResult();
```

If you want to send data to your activity, use: `putExtra`

Like this:

```
Intent intentLoad = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourNewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("radioID", id-of-your-radioButton);
startActivityForResult();
```

You can catch your id in the activity with:

```
int myRadioId = extras.getInt("radioID");
```