# Can't generate instance of RadioButton

Tags: android, radio-button

I'm trying to send a RadioButton to an activity using intent.putExtra().
I made it work with a string, and other objects, but I don't know how to create an instance of RadioButton. It's constructors are asking for Context as a parameter, which also doesn't have a simple constructor. Is there any way to generate a RadioButton object without getting it without something like this`RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton);`?

Edit: to clarify, I don't want to send a particular RadioButton, just to signal to the activity that it needs to generate a RadioButton of the characteristics, so that the next activity can add it in the list of custom views using adapters.

Comment: pass radiobutton id  instead of  radioButto like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22874630/5110595)

Comment: Why would you send `RadioButton`? Tell us what you want to achieve and I'm pretty sure there's a solution without having to do this

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by sending radiobutton in intent. this is not a way of doing things in android development. you should change the way of your task.

Comment: I need to send through a list of custom views, (which radioButton is a type of if im not wrong), so I'm trying it out with radioButton. I need to generate a form for a user to fill, and that form could have radioButtons, textFileds, checkBoxes.

Comment: ok.. then instead of putting your views in intent you should give some id or type for them. like if you select  radio button and a textview then send 1 for radiobutton & 2 for textview. in activity you will know what is for what. then generate your view according to it.

Comment: What characteristics do you need to share?

Comment: Text of the radioButton is just one example, I guess I should have generalized my quesition a bit more, since it relates to all the custom views.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot send `Context` via `Intent`, but you need it for `RadioButton` constuction. You can ue it in your second activity. If you are sending label for `RadioButton` as a `String` then try this:

**ActivityOne**

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("label", "This is label");
startActivity(i);
```

**ActivityTwo**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
    rb.setText(getIntent().getStrignExtra("label"));

    LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    main.addView(rb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `RadioButton` is a `View`, this means it belongs in a View hierarchy and can't be freely sent between them.

Additionally an intent can only send `Parcelable` data (Views are not Parcelable) or `Serializable` data. While it's technically possible to do this, it's definitely the wrong approach for any case (at best you want to send the data represented by the radio button)

The main reason for not sending a view is that it is tied to `Context`. For this case you can think of context as the individual screen. You don't want to have an item on one screen, that can only work on another screen.

**ActivityA**

```
public static final String EXTRA_RADIO = "EXTRA_RADIO";

Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RADIO, value);
startActivity(intent);
```

**ActivityB**

```
public void onCreate(...) {
    ...

    RadioButton radio = findViewById(...);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        //examples - depending on data type
        String value = bundle.getString(ActivityA.EXTRA_RADIO);
        int value = bundle.getInteger(ActivityA.EXTRA_RADIO);

        radio.setText(value);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks for explaining how context works, I think I got it now. Combined with the answer above, I should make it work, thanks again!